# Linux : Copy Multiple files and remove it's extension

Tags: linux, file, ubuntu, copy, copy-paste

I have got a directory containing files of type *.cpp.So i would like to copy each file in the directory and to paste it in the same directory by using

```
 cp -a *.cpp
```

with an option to remove the .cpp while pasting.Is it possible ?

Comment: Although there are plenty of options for `mv` and `cp` I'm not aware a direct solution for your case. Consider writing a simple script (bash, python, whatever) that copies and renames each file. Also I'm sure there are many tools available that help with file management. Maybe they provide a solution for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a simple bash script.  This script assumes that the file name only contains one "." character and splits based on that.

```
#!/bin/sh

for f in *.cpp; do

#This line splits the file name on the delimiter "."
baseName=`echo $f | cut -d "." -f 1`
newExtension=".new"

cp $f $baseName$newExtension

done
```

Comment: Can i change ".new" to "" .

Comment: Yes, you can change newExtension to whatever you like.

Comment: So how to run this script and cp filename.cpp to just filename from command line. I don't know how to use this script .

Comment: Here is a good tutorial on how to run a bash script.  After you've gotten a simple script working from a tutorial, just put in the text in the script above.   http://linuxcommand.org/wss0010.php

Comment: @user143903 How to run the command to cp files and save it with new extension in command line . eg like this  :cp *.cpp * (I want this command based on your bash script).

Comment: 1.  In a text editor, create a file named "rename_extension.sh".  2.  Copy the text from the answer above into this file and save it.  3.  Open a shell and cd to the directory.  4. run command "chmod 755 rename_extension.sh"  5.  Execute the script by typing "./rename_extension.sh".

Answer (score 5):

You can do this just by means of bash parameter extension, as mentioned in the bash manual:

> ${parameter%%word}
>                 Remove matching suffix pattern.  The word is expanded to produce
>                 a pattern just as in pathname expansion.  If the pattern matches
>                 a  trailing portion of the expanded value of parameter, then the
>                 result of the expansion is the expanded value of parameter  with
>                 the  shortest  matching  pattern (the ``%'' case) or the longest
>                 matching pattern (the ``%%'' case) deleted.
>   ...

```
for i in *.cpp
do
     cp -a $i ${i%%.cpp}
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Can use **rename**, optionally with **-f** to force rewrite existing files.

```
rename -f 's/\.ext$//' *.ext
```

To preview actions, but don't change files, use **-n** switch (No action).

This is not copy but move :-(